# given a number n , we have to find out such numbers that are less than or equal to n, that have exactly 3 divisors

Tags: java, primes

i have used sieve of eratosthenes method to calculate such numbers that have exactly 3 divisors and are less than or equal to n where n is the given number.

the problem with this code is that it give answer 37386 for n=999999,but the correct answer is 168

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Scanner scn =new Scanner(System .in);
    print("enter the prime no");
    int n= scn.nextint();
    int arr[]= new int[n+1];
    for(int i=2;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=1;
    }

    for(int i=2;i*i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]==1)
        {

            for(int p=2;p*i<=n;p++)
            {
                arr[p*i]=0;
            }
        }
    }

    int count=0;
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]==1&&i*i<n)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.print(count);
}
```

[code for calculating numbers that have exactly 3 divisors](https://ideone.com/bGtlf6)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please remember that this is not a general help forum, and you are expected to put some work into your question. Give [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) a thorough read-through, and update your post so that your code is concisely formatted, and describe what you've already tried/analysed to figure out where the problem might be, even if you couldn't actually solve it. If there's no sign that you even tried to figure out the problem, then that's usually the first request for you to do.

Comment: consider number 4 its has divisors 1,2,4(3 divisors) now consider number 9 it has divisors 1,3,9 . consider number 25 it has divisors 1,5,25  these are some numbers that have exactly 3 divisors

Comment: @DeepakMishra  Ah, I see.  So basically it's the square of a prime number.

Answer (score 0):

The Sieve of Eratosthenes is used to calculate prime numbers. Your code correctly calculates that there are 37386 prime numbers less than 999999. It should be possible to modify the code to find numbers with exactly three divisors rather than one, but I will leave that as an exercise to the asker.

Comment: "but I will leave that as an exercise to the asker" - So why answer?

Comment: sir i have found my mistake in the code but unable to get it

Comment: https://ideone.com/bGtlf6  the mistake is in last for loop code but i did not understand  why about it

Comment: The number of primes less than 999999 is 78498. Check out [this](http://www.mathematical.com/primes0to1000k.html)